# Nginx Reverse Proxy SSL / Minification

Tags: iis-7, nginx, minify, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use NginX as a reverse proxy for a few IIS Servers.  The goal is to have NginX sit in from of the IIS / Apache servers caching static items such as CSS / JS / Images.  I am also trying to get NginX to automatically minify js / css files using its perl module.

I found a sample script for minification here:

http://petermolnar.eu/linux-tech-coding/nginx-perl-minify-css-js/

With the scrip everything works fine, except the reverse proxy breaks.

Questions:

1. Is what i am trying to accomplish even possible?  I want NginX to first minify the scripts before saving them to cache.
2. Can nginX automtically set the proper expires headers so that static items are cached as long as possible, and only replaced when querystrings are changed  (jquery.js?timestamp=march-2012)
3. Can NginX GZIP the resources before sending them out.
4. Can NGinx Forward requests or serve up a "Down For Maintenance page" if it cannot connec to back end server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what i have in my sites-enabled/default so far.

```
    server {


    location / {

        proxy_pass             http://mywebsite.com;
        proxy_set_header       Host $host;
        proxy_cache            STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
                              http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }


    location @minify {
                    perl Minify::minify_handler;
            }

            location ~ \.css$ {
                    try_files $uri.min.css @minify;
            }




            location /*.js {
                 expires 30d;
            }



}
```

Comment: The person that posted the config is likely to have a better insight. There is a comments section you can use on the linked site.

Comment: I tried also posting there. If he answers I will make sure to bring it over to stack overflow.  I am trying to figure out if its a good use case.  Right now we run a mix of IIS7 and Apache.  We use RequestReduce on IIS7 which is a great way to minify and combine, but having that done at thee Proxy level makes sense.  Being able to push a small js or css change to our main servers and have them minified on first request sounds sexy.  Specially in cases where NginX is used to create a CDN like the guys at maxcdn / netdna.

Comment: BTW, cloudflare cdn offers a lot of the minify / cdn built in one.  The problem is they have major latency complaints.  http://x-pose.org/2012/02/speed-up-your-site-disable-cloudflare/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nginx is the ideal solution for reverse-proxy, it's also Unix way "do one thing and do it well". So I'd advice you to split content serve and minification process out instead of using third-party plugins to do many things at once.

Best practice is to do minify&obfuscate phase on local system before you do a deployment on production, this is easy to say and not hard to do, see [the google way](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript) to compress static assets.  Once you got assets ready-to-use, we can setup nginx configuration.

Answers:

1. use minify&obfuscate before deploy it on production
2. you can find assets by regexp (directory name or file extension)

   location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
     gzip_static       on;
     expires           max;
     add_header        Cache-Control public;
     add_header        Last-Modified "";
     add_header        ETag "";
     break;
   }
3. use **gzip on** and **gzip_static on** to serve gzipped files instead of compress it every time when request is coming.
4. use **try_files** to detect the maintenance page exists or not

   try_files           $uri /system/maintenance.html @mywebsite;

   if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
     return            503;
   }

See the full nginx config for your case:

```
http {
  keepalive_timeout         70;

  gzip                      on;
  gzip_http_version         1.1;
  gzip_disable              "msie6";
  gzip_vary                 on;
  gzip_min_length           1100;
  gzip_buffers              64 8k;
  gzip_comp_level           3;
  gzip_proxied              any;
  gzip_types                text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml;

  upstream mywebsite {
    server                  192.168.0.1 # change it with your setting
  }

  server {
    try_files               $uri /system/maintenance.html @mywebsite;

    location @mywebsite {
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header      Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect        off;
      proxy_pass            http://mywebsite;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
      gzip_static       on;
      expires           max;
      add_header        Cache-Control public;
      add_header        Last-Modified "";
      add_header        ETag "";
      break;
    }

    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      return            503;
    }

    location @503 {
      error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
      if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
        rewrite         ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
      }
      rewrite           ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: to build nginx with optimized settings, you can use this gist https://gist.github.com/3052776

Comment: I dont know why this was voted down, Its a great start.  But what we are trying to do is Minify directly before the reverse proxy.  The reason for this is we have a blend of IIS / Apache servers.  Minification on IIS is limited when not working with MVC. Doing it manually is just plain unsexy and creates extra todos everytime we push an update.

Comment: @Frank I see what you mean, but let me explain how we handle the assets compression. Due to the fact we have zero-downtime deployment, we tried to reduce deployment time, all extra work has been completed before ship with special scripts, it's all automated. After that everything is going to be committed in a repo. I have a question about this perl module - how this avoid the dogpile effect?

Comment: what is a dogpile effect?  I am simply curious if nginx has the ability to run a "script" then proxy store a content.  This can also be a cool feature for mail proxying.

Comment: @Frank dog-pile effect happens once multiple clients at the same time  do the request to generate cache (or the similar approach to minimize the assets static). It can cause an extra load on server-side by execution multiple perl scripts at once.

Comment: I think what I am trying to do is.  1. Nginx reaches out to IIS and pulls the copy.  2. Minimizes the CSS / JS files 3.Caches them to disk, so that they are not minimized again.   I am simply baffled why more are not trying to do it like this.